# installed mod_deflate but no improvement

Tags: mod-deflate

I have installed the mod_deflate on centos. In virtual host file I have added the following

```
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$  no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI  \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary

  DeflateFilterNote Input input_info
  DeflateFilterNote Output output_info
  DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio_info
  LogFormat '"%r" %{output_info}n/%{input_info}n (%{ratio_info}n%%)' deflate
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/deflate_log deflate
```

its show the compression in log also but not showing improvement in pageloading time.

Please guide for the same.

Comment: Did the deflation work at least (even if it did not improve load times)?

Answer (score 0):

if its still not working a possible reasone will be you have not included this

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

in apache

```
httpd.conf
```

Comment: I have not said its not working !!! I am getting the same speed that was erliar without mod_deflate.  After installing the mod_deflate there is no difference in page loading. In log file there was a compression but its effect not showing in page loading time.